# OpenGL can't create window object

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I've bee trying to make a class for a window and I'm not sure why this error shows up.
I've been also trying to add the functions and everything else manually into the "main.cpp" file to check if openGl is working, and it does, but when I try to make a openGl object, it's not working.
Maybe the problem it's easy to spot, but I can't figure it out.(sorry I'm just trying to learn here :3 )

[image]

Here is my code:
The header file

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class Window {
private:
    const char* p_title;
    int p_width;
    int p_height;
    GLFWwindow* window;
public:
    Window(const char* title, int width, int height);
    ~Window();
    bool close();
    void update();
private:
    void init();
};
```

The .cpp file

```
#include "window .h"


Window::Window(const char* title, int width, int height)
{
    p_title = title;
    p_width = width;
    p_height = height;
    init();
}

Window::~Window()
{
    glfwTerminate();
}

bool Window::close()
{
    return glfwWindowShouldClose(window);
}

void Window::update()
{
    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}

void Window::init()
{
    window = glfwCreateWindow(p_width, p_height, p_title, NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        std::cout << "The window could not be created\n";
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
}
```

If it helps, here is the debugger:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you didn't call glfwInit()

Comment: What does the 'Call stack' tab show?

Comment: This is the 'Call stack' tab 
https://imgur.com/a/X2WqWJ7

Comment: You probably should add `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` after `glfwTerminate();` because if you can't create the window you don't want the program to continue.

Comment: Omg... yea I forgot to add glfwinit() thank you